# how to use trigger in order to increase or decrease stock in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm creating a MySQL database.

**Tables:**

Sales(`id, idoftheproduct, quantity`) and

Supplies(`id, idoftheproduct, quantity`).

I want a trigger that whenever we add a new sale or a new supply, it will increase or decrease the values of a different table which is called Stock(`idoftheproduct, quantity`)

Answer (score 1):

In short, don't. Instead create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html):

```
CREATE VIEW Stock
AS
    SELECT  IDofTheProduct, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM    (   SELECT  IDofTheProduct, Quantity
                FROM    Supplies
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  IdOfTheProduct, -Quantity
                FROM    Sales
            ) t
    GROUP BY IDofTheProduct;
```

This way whever your underlying tables change your view will change. This is less overhead during updates/inserts, and will always be accurate, even if the trigger did not fire for some reason.

**EDIT**

Apologies, I forgot that MySQL does not allow subqueries in views. One solution would be to create a new view to use instead of a subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW SalesAndSupplies
AS
    SELECT  'Supplies' AS `Type`,
            IDofTheProduct, 
            Quantity
    FROM    Supplies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  'Sales' AS `Type`,
            IDofTheProduct, 
            -Quantity
    FROM    Sales;

CREATE VIEW Stock
AS
    SELECT  IDofTheProduct, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM    SalesAndSupplies
    GROUP BY IDofTheProduct;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab85a5/1)**

Comment: thanks garethD, but with this solution i get an error 1349(View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with a view is a great one, but it tends to become slower over the time especially if you have lots of sales and supplies data since you always compute it.

Therefore if you decide to implement it via triggers then you have to have at least four triggers (insert and delete on both tables). Since all them update the stock that part of the code is better be factored out to a stored procedure.

Stored procedure that updates the stock

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_update_stock(IN pid INT, IN qty DECIMAL(11, 3))
    INSERT INTO stock (idoftheproduct, quantity) 
    VALUES (pid, qty)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = quantity + qty;
```

*If a row with an `idoftheproduct` doesn't exist at the moment of execution then it will be created. Otherwise it'll be updated to reflect the change.*

Now triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_sales_insert
AFTER INSERT ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
    CALL sp_update_stock(NEW.idoftheproduct, -1 * NEW.quantity);

 CREATE TRIGGER tg_supplies_insert
 AFTER INSERT ON supplies
 FOR EACH ROW
    CALL sp_update_stock(NEW.idoftheproduct, NEW.quantity);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_sales_delete
AFTER DELETE ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
    CALL sp_update_stock(OLD.idoftheproduct, OLD.quantity);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_supplies_delete
AFTER DELETE ON supplies
FOR EACH ROW
    CALL sp_update_stock(OLD.idoftheproduct, -1 * OLD.quantity);
```

Now you can insert and delete to and from Sales and Supplies.

```
INSERT INTO Supplies VALUES (NULL, 1, 100), (NULL, 1, 50), (NULL, 1, 75);
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES (NULL, 1, 2),(NULL, 1, 10), (NULL, 1, 5);
DELETE FROM Sales WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM Supplies WHERE id = 3;
```

If take a look at `stock` will see

```
| IDOFTHEPRODUCT | QUANTITY |
-----------------------------
|              1 |      135 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff419/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case as you, if I will create a supplier, sales, detail_stock, and detail_supplier table, then the table that has the name *detail* in front of it will have columns for the primary key, foreign keys from the goods and supplier tables, supplier shipping amount (for supplier shipping details), purchase amount (for the purchase table), then the last is the purchase status or supplier shipping status (here I use two statuses for each details). I use this status to trigger the trigger that I made as a query below.

```
-- TRIGGER
DELIMITER /
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_purchase
AFTER INSERT ON detail_status_transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE quantity_of_items_purchased  INT;

    SET quantity_of_items_purchased = NEW.quantity_purchased;

    IF NEW.status_transaction = 'Completed' THEN
        -- Update stock_book
        UPDATE book
        SET stock_book = stock_book - quantity_of_items_purchased 
        WHERE book_id = (SELECT book_id FROM transaction WHERE id_nota = NEW.transaction_id);
    elseif NEW.transaction_status = 'Refund' then
        update book
        set stock_book = stock_book + quantity_of_items_purchased 
        where id_book = (select book_id from transaction where id_nota = NEW.transaction_id);
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger update supplier

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_supplier
AFTER INSERT ON detail_status_supplier
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE  quantity_buy_items INT;

    SET  quantity_buy_items= NEW.quantity_shipped;

    IF NEW.status_supplier = 'Success' THEN
        -- Update book stock (supplier)
        UPDATE book
        SET stock_book = stock_book + quantity_buy_items
        WHERE id_book = (SELECT id_book FROM book WHERE id_book = NEW.book_id);
    elseif NEW.status_supplier = 'Failed' then
        update book
        set stock_book = stock_book -  quantity_buy_items
        where id_book = (SELECT id_book FROM book WHERE id_book = NEW.book_id);
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Then by triggering this trigger by entering input into the *details* table will make the stock decrease or increase according to what is triggered and according to the desired conditions.